# Can You Create an Astro Custom Directive?

Tags: astrojs

Is there anyway to add your own custom directive to `Astro`?

Something like the `class:list` one.

This page lists all the directives, but nothing about adding your own custom one:

https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/

What I'm wanting to do is simplify this when integrating Apline:

```
x-data={JSON.stringify({items:right})}
```

I'd like to write a directive that did this:

```
json:tag-name={{items:right}}
```

Which would render `tag-name="{items: 'varValue'}"`.

I've scoured the docs/google to no avail.

Comment: What are you looking for the directive to do? If passed to a component, you can use a prop and the component can handle that.